# Plot normal distribution onto data

Tags: r, ggplot2, normal-distribution

I have some lognormal data that I want to transform, then fit a normal distribution to. Here is a reproducible example with data that's not exactly lognormal, but it's close enough:

```
# create some lognormal data
dat <- data.frame(x = c(runif(1000, 0, 1), runif(300, 1, 100), runif(100,100,1000)))
```

I can transform these data by `log10` and fit a normal distribution to them with `MASS::fitdistr`.

```
# fit normal distribution to log-transformed values
library(MASS)
fit <- fitdistr(log10(dat$x), densfun = "normal")
fit$estimate # mean and SD of the normal distribution
```

Now I want to plot the data, and the distribution on top of it. I transform my data by log10, and plot the normal distribution with `stat_function`, but it's not fitting the data.

```
# plot data and distribution
ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = log10(x))) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = fit$estimate[1], sd = fit$estimate[2], log = TRUE))
```

[image]

Any pointers, as well as verification if I'm going about this correctly, would be very helpful.

Lastly to get my x axis in displaying units of 10, 100, 1000, etc... should I use `scale_x_log10()`? What's a simple way to format the x axis?

Comment: log(uniform distribution) is _not_ lognormal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to draw on the same graph a histogram and a density distribution you need to plot a **density histogram** using the aesthetic `y=..density..`
Here is an example. To make things clear, I generated data from a lognormal distribution.

```
set.seed(123)
# Generate data from a log-normal distribution
dat <- data.frame(x=rlnorm(10000))

# Fit normal distribution to log-transformed values
library(MASS)
fit <- fitdistr(log10(dat$x), densfun = "normal")

# Plot density histogram and fitted distribution
ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = log10(x), y = ..density..), col="white") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
      args = list(mean = fit$estimate[1], sd = fit$estimate[2], log = F), 
      color="red", lwd=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Marco! One more (perhaps quick) question, what do you recommend for formatting the x axis in this example? Would you use `scale_x_log10()` or `simply scale_x_continuous()` with breaks and labels arguments at 1, 10, 100, 1000... ?

Comment: @RichPauloo In my opinion, the x axis of the above plot is ok. The interpretation is clear: on the x axis there are the log values of x, hence 1 means 10, 2 means 100, and so on...

Comment: @RichPauloo Otherwise, you can use `scale_x_continuous`. In my opinion  you should not use `scale_x_log10()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Marco, and the super clear example. :)

Comment: @RichPauloo You did the most part of the code ! You only forgot to use density instead of counts..!